# Objective-c Call a shared delegation method from the delegate

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, delegates

I have these files:

```
someDelegate.h
someDelegate.m
```

In someDelegate.h there is the function foo() which should be shared by all the classes that implement someDelegate. foo() is implemented in someDelegate.m

Now I have the class Bar which implements someDelegate and I want to call the method foo() from within a Bar method declared in Bar.m

```
int result = [self foo];
```

This does not work. How should I call the function foo() from every class that implements someDelegate without declaring the function multiple times?

Comment: What are the actual definitions of `someDelegate` and `Bar`?  How and where is `foo` defined?  (You call it both a function and a method.)

Comment: For example someDelegate defines a game player, and classes A,B,C implement a game play at different strengths. But lets say classes A,B and C all need some custom sorting function: +(void) sort:(NSMutableArray *) arr;

Comment: Since it's a class method, they just call it: `[SomeSortUtility sort:myMutableArray];`  However, that has nothing to do with delegation and doesn't seem related to your original question.

Comment: No, I'd rather not make a separate class for my sort function, since it would be just a class with one (1) class function. So I'd like to associate it with the gamePlayer classes. That is why I put it in the delegate and implemented it in the delegate.m. But maybe that is just not how the delegation system works and I should indeed make a separate class for the helper functions that only benefit the classes that implement the specific delegate.

Comment: You didn't say where you were putting the `sort` but `[SomeDelegate sort:myMutableArray];` is also valid.  (I used a different name because, as I said, it's not at all related to the delegate pattern.)